# Is there a less ugly way to get a sliding window in R

Tags: r

I would like to get a sliding window `em` from a vector `x`, something like this

```
x <- 1:10
em <- embed(x,dimension = 3) [,3:1]
em <- rbind(matrix(NA,nrow = length(x)-nrow(em),ncol = ncol(em)),em)
```

..

```
em
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2    3
 [4,]    2    3    4
 [5,]    3    4    5
 [6,]    4    5    6
 [7,]    5    6    7
 [8,]    6    7    8
 [9,]    7    8    9
[10,]    8    9   10
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But I absolutely do not like the code, it is cumbersome and poorly understood.
Can you suggest your own options that seem more concise to you?

=======
made a little comparison

```
   n <- 5
x <- 1:200

fu1 <- function(x, n){
  m <- embed(x,dimension = n) [,n:1]
  rbind(matrix(NA,nrow = length(x)-nrow(m),ncol = ncol(m)),m)
  m
}

fu2 <- function(x, n){
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = n)
  m[n:length(x),] <- t(sapply(1:(length(x)-(n-1)), function(i) x[i:(i+(n-1))]))
  m
}

fu3 <- function(x, n){
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = n)
  for (i in n:length(x))  m[i,] <- x[(i-(n-1)):(i)]
  m
}

fu4 <- function(x, n){
  m <- zoo::rollapply(data = x, width = n, FUN = as.list)
  m <- rbind(matrix(NA,nrow = length(x)-nrow(m),ncol = ncol(m)),m)
  m
}

fu5 <- function(x, n){
  zoo::rollapplyr(x, n, c, fill = NA)
}

fu6 <- function(x, n){
k <- seq_along(x)
idx <- c(outer(head(k, 1 - n), head(k - 1, n), `+`))
m <- matrix(x[idx], ncol = n)
rbind(matrix(NA,nrow = length(x)-nrow(m),ncol = ncol(m)),m)
}

fu7 <- function(x, n){
m <- t(sapply(head(seq_along(x), 1 - n), \(k) x[k:(k + (n-1))]))
rbind(matrix(NA,nrow = length(x)-nrow(m),ncol = ncol(m)),m)
}
```

.....

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark( fu1(x,n), 
                                fu2(x,n), 
                                fu3(x,n), 
                                fu4(x,n),
                                fu5(x,n),
                                fu6(x,n),
                                fu7(x,n))
Unit: microseconds
      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 fu1(x, n)    90.657   120.5910   140.4726   133.4195   142.5420   511.441   100
 fu2(x, n)   898.586  1011.4790  1295.2010  1071.6320  1174.2625 11882.315   100
 fu3(x, n)   322.716   371.4650   851.5983   387.4300   417.3635 23120.339   100
 fu4(x, n)  8308.497  9917.2290 11594.9786 10481.1260 11391.4000 37111.138   100
 fu5(x, n) 23263.451 26653.6745 29845.5357 27709.9120 30243.4565 80859.609   100
 fu6(x, n)   192.147   238.0455   271.7939   270.2610   291.3560   522.844   100
 fu7(x, n)   933.936  1078.7590  1343.0666  1146.6095  1203.3410 11592.100   100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zoo package's `rollapply`

```
x <- 1:10
zoo::rollapply(data = x, width = 3, FUN = as.list)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1    2    3   
[2,] 2    3    4   
[3,] 3    4    5   
[4,] 4    5    6   
[5,] 5    6    7   
[6,] 6    7    8   
[7,] 7    8    9   
[8,] 8    9    10
```

You can pad `x` with enough NAs if you want the rows with NAs as well.

Comment: yes, I need rows with NA..
thanks!

Comment: This should be `rollapplyr(1:10, 3, c, fill = NA)` Note the r at the end of rollapplyr which results in right window alignment so that the rows of NA's go at the beginning. Other alignments are possible too -- see the align argument of rollapply in ?rollapply Also as.list will result in a list with dimensions whereas a normal R matrix is a plain numeric vector with dimensions so use c in place of as.list. Finally fill=NA will fill with NA's.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck thanks, great solution

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stay with base R but not to use `embed`, here are some alternatives (but I don't believe they can be more performant or elegant than `embed`)

- `outer`

```
k <- seq_along(x)
idx <- c(outer(head(k, 1 - l), head(k - 1, l), `+`))
matrix(x[idx], ncol = l)
```

- `sapply`

```
t(sapply(head(seq_along(x), 1 - l), \(k) x[k:(k + 2)]))
```